# Delete file from folder where contains

Tags: c#, .net

I am looking to create a Method which I can use to delete files from a directory when the filename contains the wildcard parameter.

So far I have the below but I cannot seem to work out how I can delete any files from my fileEntries collection that contain the wildcard.

```
public static void DeleteFileContaining(string targetDirectory, string wildcard)
        {
            // Process the list of ALL files found in the directory. 
            string[] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(targetDirectory);

            foreach (var item in fileEntries)
            {               
                var itemToDelete = fileEntries.Contains(wildcard);
                 // delete where contains                
            }
        }
```

Can anyone finish this or suggest a more efficient way of doing this in one neat method call which takes the directory and wildcard?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz42302f(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Why aren't you using Directory.GetFiles(directory, pattern)? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz42302f(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the search-pattern of `GetFiles`/`EnumerateFiles`(which can be more efficient):

```
public static void DeleteFileContaining(string targetDirectory, string wildcard)
{
    string searchPattern = string.Format("*{0}*", wildcard);
    var filesToDelete = Directory.EnumerateFiles(targetDirectory, searchPattern);
    foreach (var fileToDelete in filesToDelete)
    {
        try{
            File.Delete(fileToDelete);
        }catch(Exception ex){
            // log this...
        }
    }
}
```

Look at the [remarks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd413233.aspx) section for further information.

Answer (score 1):

First off, this line is wrong:

```
var itemToDelete = fileEntries.Contains(wildcard);
```

This returns a boolean indicating whether at least one of the filenames is an exact match. What you want is:

```
var items = fileEntries.Where(name => name.Contains(wildcard));
```

Second, you don't even need to filter the filenames like this, you can simply use this other [`GetFiles` overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz42302f%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)  that takes a search pattern.

Finally, you can then use [`File.Delete`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.delete.aspx) to actually delete those files.

Comment: I followed your suggestion however my method is not deleting the files with the requestId in the name: 

        public static void DeleteFileContaining(string targetDirectory, string wildcard)
        {
            // Process the list of ALL files found in the directory. 
            string[] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(targetDirectory, "*@wildcard*");

            foreach (var item in fileEntries)
            {
                File.Delete(item);
            }           

        }

Answer (score 1):

This is my first stab at something like this with LINQ, but this worked for me:

```
public static void DeleteFileContaining(string targetDirectory, string wildcard)
{
    Directory.GetFiles(targetDirectory).Where(j => j.Contains(wildcard)).ToList().ForEach(i => File.Delete(i));
}
```

Or this uses a multiline lambda expression to include error handling:

```
public static void DeleteFileContaining(string targetDirectory, string wildcard)
{
    Directory.GetFiles(targetDirectory).Where(j => j.Contains(wildcard)).ToList().ForEach(i =>
        {
            try
            {
                File.Delete(i);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {                        
                //do something here on exception.
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: Wow - that is a horrible abuse of LINQ.

Comment: @DanielKelley -- Please elaborate.  Seriously.  I'm "new" to LINQ.

Comment: LINQ is a tool for querying. The code above produces a side-effect, which is not desirable. Your code is essentially fine up until your use `ForEach` to delete the files. You should then use a regular `foreach` loop to iterate over them and delete them.

Comment: @DanielKelley By the point a side-effect is produced, he's not using LINQ anymore, just regular `List<T>` methods. I don't think this is an "abuse", it's just a more *functional* way of expressing your intent, instead of doing it in an *imperative* style.

Comment: Still, I wouldn't use this code because it doesn't check for exceptions (which is *very* important when dealing with the file system) and because `Directory.EnumerateFiles` is more efficient (and applying `ToList` after calling `EnumerateFiles` wouldn't make any sense).

Comment: Thanks to both.  From where I sit, it still looks like a pretty nifty one-liner, and it worked -- in a split second, too, when I tested it on 4000 files.

Comment: I mean, I know I'm playing the Devil's advocate here, because I'm all for reducing code smell and all that, but you have to wonder sometimes how far you need to take efforts at increasing code efficiency.  It depends on the situation, I think.

Comment: @roryap I agree, efficiency is arguable, but robustness isn't.

Comment: If you're trying to express this in a functional style, I'd change the last bit to `ForEach(TryDelete)` and then implement a `void TryDelete(string filename)` method that deletes the file and handles exceptions.

Comment: @dcastro -- I agree totally.  Good thought.

Comment: @dcastro -- I've added some code to my answer.  Better?

Comment: Here's a blog post from Eric Lippert where he discusses [`foreach` vs `ForEach`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx)

Comment: good ,  you can use  Directory.GetFiles(picturePath).ToList().ForEach(File.Delete); for delete all old picture for seed class

Answer (score 0):

I would use the wildcard to get only the files that I am interested in.

```
public static void DeleteFileContaining(string targetDirectory, string wildcard){
        string[] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(targetDirectory, wildcard);//something like *.jpg

        // delete all matching files. 
        foreach (string f in fileEntries)
        {
            File.Delete(f);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure you want to delete from folder but as you have mentioned you want to remove from fileEntries collection you can achieve by this

```
fileEntries = fileEntries.Where(a => !a.Contains(wildcard)).ToArray();
```

Comment: I do want to delete then from a folder, I am storing every payment object on the file system temporarily and then only deleting them once the payment processes successfully.

Comment: @SelectDistinct Okay, then you can use `File.Delete` function. anyway you already got an answer. good luck! :)

Answer (score -1):

You might want to look at the System.IO-Class to delete files ([http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.IO(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.IO%28v=vs.110%29.aspx))

Comment: This doesn't address the OP's question, which is not *how* to delete, rather how to delete only when needed an in an efficient manner.